# Python not printing values in loop

Tags: python

Here is a sample code that I tried running:

```
import sys
while True:
    print "Hello World"
    #sys.stdout.write("Hello World")
    #sys.stderr.write("Hello World")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

This runs fine and prints "Hello World" when ran from the python interpreter.
The problem is when I try to run it as follows and writing to a pipe does not work with print and stdout even if I flush the output. It only works when I uncomment the `sys.stderr.write()`.

`python test.py | tail -n 1`

Kindly note that it only occurs when the print statement is in a loop. Can anyone help me understand why it behaves this way?

Thanks

Comment: Why describe the issue rather than provide runnable code that illustrates the thing that surprises you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're producing endless output and `tail -n 1` is waiting for the *last* line of input from stdin, which never arrives.

Comment: Thanks @Iguananaut for the help. It seems I was overthinking. But as a followup, anything but last line will be written to standard error? I have accepted your answer as my primary question has been answered.

Comment: I'm not sure--that sounds tricky and might not be doable as a one-liner.  Though if you ask that as a separate question I'm sure there's a bash wizard out there who can answer it.